# Problems with iRODS plugin compilation

Tags: c++, makefile, include

I'm currently working on a project that includes working with iRODS compound types.

Anyhow, my Makefile has only 3 directives. One is for creating the shared library, second is for creating a test harness executable, and third one is cleanup.

First and third are working properly, but whenever I try to compile test_harness executable I get the very strange error that it has an undefined reference to rodsLog.

But it shouldn't be possible, since my VSCode configuration has got everything included in path.

**Snippet from c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/usr/include/c++/6",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/clang/4.0.0/include",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include/irods",
                "/usr/include/irods/boost"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include/c++/6",
                    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/lib/clang/4.0.0/include",
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                    "/usr/include/irods",
                    "/usr/include/irods/boost"

                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
```

My **Makefile** looks like this:

```
GCC = g++
INC=-I/usr/include/irods/ -I/usr/include/irods/boost/
LIB=-L/usr/lib/irods/
all:
    ${GCC} ${INC} ${LIB} -g -Wall -Dlinux_platform -fPIC -shared -o libdsnet.so libirods_dsnet.cpp \
    s3_api.cpp \
    cso_api.cpp \
    json_commands.cpp \
    -ls3 \
    -ljansson \
    -lxml2 \
    -lcurl \
    -lpthread

test_harness:
    ${GCC} ${INC} -Dlinux_platform -fPIC -o test_harness test_harness.cpp json_commands.cpp cso_api.cpp \
    s3_api.cpp \
    -lpthread \
    -ljansson \
    -lcrypto \
    -lssl \
    -ls3 \
    -lcurl



clean:
    @rm -f libdsnet.so
    @rm -f test_harness
```

Error I have is:

```
make test_harness
g++ -I/usr/include/irods/ -I/usr/include/irods/boost/ -Dlinux_platform -fPIC -o test_harness test_harness.cpp json_commands.cpp cso_api.cpp \
s3_api.cpp \
-lpthread \
-ljansson \
-lcrypto \
-lssl \
-ls3 \
-lcurl
/tmp/ccEbKGJ9.o: In function `responseCompleteCallback(S3Status, S3ErrorDetails const*, void*)':
s3_api.cpp:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `rodsLog'
```

Yet I have it included in the file + function that shows error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "irods_error.hpp"
#include "rodsLog.hpp"
#include "s3_api.hpp"
#include "rodsErrorTable.hpp"
#include <libs3.h>

static void responseCompleteCallback(
    S3Status status,
    const S3ErrorDetails *error,
    void *callbackData)
{
    int i;

    statusG = status;
    if( status != S3StatusOK ) {
        rodsLog( LOG_NOTICE, "  S3Status: [%s] - %d\n", S3_get_status_name( status ), (int) status );
    }
    if (error && error->message) {
        rodsLog( LOG_NOTICE,  "  Message: %s\n", error->message);
    }
    if (error && error->resource) {
        rodsLog( LOG_NOTICE,  "  Resource: %s\n", error->resource);
    }
    if (error && error->furtherDetails) {
        rodsLog( LOG_NOTICE, "  Further Details: %s\n", error->furtherDetails);
    }
    if (error && error->extraDetailsCount) {
        rodsLog( LOG_NOTICE,  "%s", "  Extra Details:\n");

        for (i = 0; i < error->extraDetailsCount; i++) {
            rodsLog( LOG_NOTICE,  "    %s: %s\n", error->extraDetails[i].name, error->extraDetails[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that very same code compiles for shared object, but not for test_harness, and I can't really find out why. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be missing `${LIB}`  in the `gcc` command for `test_harness`. Since this variable contains the `irods` directory and the function `rodsLog` is unresolved, this could be the problem?

Comment: @sycko And that'd be correct. Thanks mate